# iOS: Getting a strange error ever since I switch header requests library. -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, afnetworking

I am getting the error `-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]:` ever since I switched header request library to AFNetWorking. This is the code that is causing the error.

```
- (void) syncContentsFinish : (id) result
{
Content *content;
NSArray *contentsArray = [result objectForKey:@"content"];
for ( id object in contentsArray ) {
content = [Content getContentWithDictionary:object];
}
```

Specifically the `content =` method is causing this error. Here is the results I am getting from the server.

```
{
content =     {
    count = 0;
    id = 42488267526162;
};
message = success;
responseCode = 200;
}
```

I have no idea what is causing this at all but any tips or suggestions are appreciated, also if you need me to post more code (such as the handler that is retrieving the data or the `Content` class please let me know.

Edit: Actually this is misleading. In the Content class this is what I have that is actually causing the App to crash.

```
+    (Content *) getContentWithDictionary : (NSDictionary *) dic
{
   Content *content = [[Content alloc] init];
    if ( [dic objectForKey:@"id"] != [NSNull null] ) {
    content.contentId = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] longLongValue];
   }
```

Comment: Please quote the ENTIRE and EXACT error message.  In this case you're no doubt getting an *unrecognized selector* error, but in other cases it will not be so obvious, and without a complete description there is no way to solve your problem.

Comment: And learn how to obtain and interpret the exception stack trace that will tell you the EXACT line where the error occurred.

Comment: (So far you've done a lousy job of providing us with information to debug the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Its look like Content is NSString not NSDictionary.

Comment: Could u check the data type for content if([content isKindOfClass:[NSDictionry class]]) {NSlog(@"Yes");}

Comment: The data type is NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: Could u paste ur json response from server look like its has some problem

Answer (score 0):

`results` is a dictionary, that much is correct. But the value of the `"content"` key is not an array, but another dictionary. Therefore, your `for` loop is actually iterating the keys of the dictionary. This means that each `object` is an `NSString`.